# Cannot add after stop duplicates

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have been trying to stop duplicates rows in user entries, i got this work but when i add a non-existent row it is not letting me to save the entries. It should let me to add the new entrie. What's wrong?

**Model function**

```
public function get_duplicaterow() {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM intervaloshorarios INNER JOIN citas '
                . 'ON intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = citas.idIntervaloHorario '
                . 'GROUP BY citas.cita, intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario '
                . 'HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2');


        return $query->result();
    }
```

**In the main controller**

```
 $crud->set_rules('intervaloHorario', 'Franja Horaria', '_callback_doublerow_check');
```

**In the controller**

```
  public function doublerow_check() {

            $this->Fechacita_Model->get_duplicaterow();
 $q = $this->Fechacita_Model->get_duplicaterow();
        if ($count_row > 0) {
        //if count row return any row; that means you have already this email address in the database. so you must set false in this sense.
        return FALSE; // here I change TRUE to false.
    } else {
        // doesn't return any row means database doesn't have this email
        return TRUE; // And here false to TRUE
    }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `doublerow_check` function supposed to return something ?

**UPDATE**:
My guess would be that you have to return true or false. True will validate the rules that allow your new entry, false would mean your new entry does not abide by the set rules (or maybe it's the other way around ?). In your case you pass the validation if your query didn't find any rows. So, I would return something like `found rows from $q == 0`. However, are you doing this check when you want to insert a new value ? In that case, you should invalidate the entry even if only one entry already exists.

Comment: It's not working, i will update de question code. I forgot return statement but it still not working...

Comment: I don't think that returning the raw result of the query has much meaning either, check my update.

Comment: Ok i have changed this, i will update the code again, i am counting rows now but still don't work